# Access docker remote API from container

Tags: docker, docker-api, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to access Docker remote API from within a container because I need to start other containers.

The host address is `172.19.0.1`, so I'm using `http://172.19.0.1:2375/images/json` to get the list of images (from host, `http://localhost:2375/images/json` works as expected.

The connection is refused, I guess because Docker (for Windows) listens on `127.0.0.1` and not on `0.0.0.0`.

I've tried to change configuration (both from UI and `daemon.json`) adding the entry:

```
"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
```

but the daemon fails to start. How can I access the api?

Comment: You mention that you are using Docker for Windows, but don't mention which container type you are using.  Are you using Windows containers or Linux containers?

Answer (score 1):

You can set DOCKER_OPTS in windows as below and try. In Windows, Docker runs inside a VM. So, you have to ssh into the VM and make the changes.

```
DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
```

Check if it works for you.

**Update :-** To ssh into the VM (assuming default is the VM name you have created using Docker toolbox), enter the following command in the Docker Quickstart Terminal,

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#extended-description).

Comment: what's the address to ssh (or how can I find it)?

Comment: Additionally, I've found advices against exposing the socket: https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html which seems the behaviour with DOCKER_OPTS. Is the solution secure?

Comment: I don't have any docker-machine running (`docker-machine ls` returns an empty list), even if I'm able to use docker (I've installed latest Docker tools). Should I create a docker machine? and how would it be related to my "default/standard" docker instance that I'm currently using?

Comment: Yes, you will require a docker machine for this. Ideally, it should get installed when you install  [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) but you can always install it separately (refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#installing-machine-directly))

Answer (score 1):

You could link the host's /var/run/docker.sock within the container where you need it. This way, you don't expose the Docker Remote API via an open port.

Be aware that it does provide root-like access to docker.

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "tcp://host.docker.internal:2375" to connect to host machine from container. Please make sure that you can ping the "host.docker.internal" address
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976